# Sql Server 2008: How to minimise execution time of Store Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have Sql Server database and my table has 1500000 rows ...because of large amount of data 
execution time of my following procedure is very high

TABLE-----

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
[Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Link] [text] NULL,
[Title] [text] NULL,
[Duration] [text] NULL,
[Image] [text] NULL,
[Embbed] [text] NULL,
[Keywords] [text] NULL,
[Category] [text] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Id] ASC
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

PROCEDURE------

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search]
 @SearchQuery varchar(1000),
 @Id bigint
 As
BEGIN
  Select top 100 * from MyTable
  where Id > @Id and Title like '%'+@SearchQuery+'%'
```

can any one help me how do I minimise execution time of sql query on table of 1500000 rows?

Comment: Can you provide the create table statement for `MyTable` - including potential indexes on it.

Comment: Do you need to use select *, can you replace with a list of columns? Does your table have an index?

Comment: 1.5 million row is TINY - that is more a question of not smart SQL, you know. But do not say that is a lot of data - I deal with billion row databases.

Comment: yes my table has index...and i need *...but i can replace it with colum n name

Comment: yes tomtom you are right it is small data.......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You force a table scan by:

> Title like '%'+@SearchQuery+'%'

Actually no - you force definitely the non-use of an index on Title. As indices go "left to right" the "some point in the middle" query thing just turns off index use.

if ID leaves a lot to search - there you go, especially when you combine that with inappropriately slow hardware (after all 1.5 million is small data).

You either get rid of the first "%" in the LIKE statement - so an index can be used - or use full text search, which will already break up the words in the index, but even then you better get rid of the first "%".

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `LIKE` in the `WHERE` clause. You're searching text at any position within the field, which results in a possibly existing index on the `Title` column not being used.

As long as you need to search using `LIKE` for terms in the middle of the field (`LIKE '%...'`), there's probably no chance of optimizing the query runtime.

What you could try to do (even though the query engine should be smart enough to do that itself) is:

Select the entries with `ID > @ID` into a temporary table and the select the `TOP 100` from that table using the `LIKE` statement.

Comment: Should read "As long as oyu need to search using LIKE *IN THIS WAY* - you can use like and use the index, just not with a "%" before the term.

Comment: Fixed that - it was clear to me in my mind, but I didn't write it down properly :-) Is that the reason for the downvote?

Comment: actually i had used a temporary table..but now problem is when there no result for search query found..it will take so much time....

Answer (score 0):

Post your table definition, that will help us to help you. However,  there are a few things you can check:

- Make sure that your table has a `primary key` and a `clustered index`. It almost doesn't matter what they are defined on, as long as they exist. I suggest that they are defined on `Id` though, in the absence of any other information.
- Do you really need to return all columns from the table? If there are a lot of columns and you only need a few, then specify them explicitly. This will cut down the size of the resultset.
- Ask whether it is really necessary for users to do a *containing* search on `Title`. Can you get away with doing a *starts with* search instead, i.e. remove the first `'%'`? If you can do that, then the `Title` filter becomes SARGable, i.e. the query optimizer will use the index on the `Title` column instead of doing a table scan. You do have an index on `Title` don't you?

**UPDATE:**

Having seen the table definition, I notice that `Title` has type `text`. This is *very* slow to search on with a table scan, because all the data is stored outside the table row and has to be fetched separately. You can speed this up by changing it to a `varchar` type. The modern equivalent to `text` is `varchar(max)`, so try that first. However, since it's a title, are you sure you really need 2GB worth of characters in the column? Most titles of things are no more than 100 characters at most. Try measuring the length of all your titles and see if you can cut down the length of the column to something more reasonable.

In fact, looking at the names of all your columns, I can't see *anything* there that justifies the use of `text`. Even `Link`, which I assume is a URL, won't need more than `varchar(1023)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead of `TEXT` as the field types.

TEXT fields are stored in a separate location to the rest of the table whereas VARCHAR(MAX) fields are stored with the row data and so it is possible to apply full text indices on fields of this type.

Comment: As a point of principle the OP should avoid the deprecated datatypes but I'm pretty sure `text` can be full text indexed. FTS precedes SQL Server 2005 when the `MAX` datatypes were introduced.

Comment: You are indeed correct - it is possible to apply Full Text Indexing to both field types.  In this case I would use VARCHAR(MAX), apply full text indexing, and use CONTAINS instead of LIKE

Answer (score 0):

This one still open? After you have changed the text fields to varchar, and added a set rowcount statement, then you have done all you can in sql if you need to retain the leading wild card functionality. I do this type of thing regularly with no performance issues so your next step is: hardware upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

I would change your `LIKE` statement to a `CharIndex` as other have said the `LIKE` will cause a full scan of the table.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx show you how you can use the `CHARINDEX`

Comment: `CHARINDEX` isn't sargable either and so isn't  going to prevent the full scan issue.